# Close confirmation dialog when user selects negative button in setOnPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: java, android, listener, android-preferences, preferencefragment

I create `SwitchPreference` for changing value in Android settings activity. When user change the `SwitchPreference` value the 'setOnPreferenceChangeListener()' function will be invoked.

Now, I shown a dialog prompt for user confirmation for this action. When user click positive button it works normally.

But the problem is, whenever user select negative confirmation button.

In Android API 21 - The dialog prompt closed normally.

In Android API 19 - The dialog prompt opened repeatedly.

```
switchPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, final Object newValue) {
        new EasyMaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .title("Confirmation")
                .content("Are you sure?")
                .positiveText("Yes")
                .negativeText("No")
                .onPositive(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        //Works Normally
                    }})
                .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                    //The problem is here
                    //The switchPreference value changed here again
                    //So once again setOnPreferenceChangeListener is called
                        switchPreference.setChecked(!(Boolean)newValue);
                    }
                })
                .cancelable(false)
                .show();
        return false;
    }
});
```

How to change SwitchPreference's old value whenever user click negative button?

Answer (score 1):

You can temporarily *"turn off"* your listener:

```
switchPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, final Object newValue) {

        final Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener that = this;

        new EasyMaterialDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                ...
                .onNegative(new MaterialDialog.SingleButtonCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(@NonNull MaterialDialog dialog, @NonNull DialogAction which) {
                        switchPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(null);
                        switchPreference.setChecked(!(Boolean) newValue);
                        switchPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(that);
                    }
                })
                .show();

        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I got a error while adding `switchPreference.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(OnPreferenceChangeListener.this);`    Error : 'android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener' is not an enclosing class

Comment: If I click 'No' button in Dialog the PreferenceChangeListener got null value. Also the prompt get closed normally. But next time when I clicked the SwitchPreference the Listener is not called